# AudioStreamer not buffering in ios7

Tags: ios7, audiostreamer

I have a live radio streaming application developed in ios 5.1. I have used `AudioStreamer` class for the streaming and MPMusicPlayerController.now its working fine in ios 5,and 6 but in 7 its not buffering. what is there any reason for this? Can anybody hep me please

Thanks